# Are there any production-ready LINQ implementations for javascript?

Tags: javascript, linq, comparison

**Background:**

Just for laughs I decided to search to see if anyone out there had developed a JavaScript implementation of LINQ.

Lo and behold, there seem to be *several* of them. It would seem like LINQ implementations are almost like string Template processing engines: everyone and his dog has written one.

**Question:**
Does anyone out there use a LINQ implementation in production JavaScript code, and if so is there any ranking or preferences for those who have used more than one?

Comment: Seems like you would expose an *awful* lot of implementation details by using LINQ in client side code.

Comment: This question is still very valid and doesn't appear to have a very good answer!  I am looking for the answer to the same question. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't get actually what you (and maybe your dog) need. LINQ like system to query [DB](http://webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/) ? I never met this kind of projects.

If you want query JS arrays/objects you can try something like [**JSLINQ**](http://www.codeplex.com/JSLINQ) , [**JLINQ**](http://www.jlinq.net/docs/) and [**JSINQ**](http://www.codeplex.com/jsinq) .

*P.S. My dog is inspired and wants implement something like these and name it **JINQ** :)*

Comment: Mushex, LOL. Im the author of jinqJs.com  so I was close :)

Answer (score 1):

Pls check out..very impressive.

[hugoware jLINQ](http://www.hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq)

[Also on Codeplex](http://jlinq.codeplex.com/)